# Managing iPod in Ubuntu 12.04, using rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

When i try to use rhythmbox to add or remove songs from my iPod which is :

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05ac:1265 Apple, Inc. iPod Nano 5.Gen
```

I get:

```
 Error opening file '/media/029f4818-0a60-3482-bf31-75e440cd38e0/iPod_Control/Music/F13/song ~FU.mp3': Read-only file system
```

I set it to manually manage music on the another PC with iTunes, and I restored it before that.
I've tried things like songbird and gtkpod in the past but they didn't work on other versions of ubuntu.
**Is it true that apple makes it so that you can't use iPods on non-mac or non-windows machines?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the filesystem of the iPod to enter R/W mode

`mount /dev/sdc2 /media/ipod`

If asked to initialize it, please do.

Configure it to make sure the type of iPod is recognized, or if not correctly recognized, select it. then Connect.

Load files and folders into a Playlist, transfer the files, and when transfer completes and the screen confirms it's ready to disconnect, select Disconnect, Eject the iPod and unmount it.

Comment: I don't think I'm using the mount command correctly...   http://pastebin.com/gak9F8Uv